# Which new features will Loki have?

Tags: release-loki

I have heard something about the next release of elementary OS, named Loki. Which new features are planned and published yet? I have a new software center or elementary market in mind. Anything else?

**EDIT (To reply closing this question)**: Please add only features which are published yet. Answers of this question could cover the whole developing process of Loki.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about speculation about future events. Any answers posted here aren't necessarily accurate and can only be speculation.

Comment: I don't think so. The answer could be a collection of news about Loki. You are right: If the question is answered now, only rumours are covered. But for a longer time, this could be the chance to cover the developing of Loki.

Comment: I don't think we want to re-open this question until Loki is actually in active development. There's no focus on that right now, it's all for the Freya update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no final list.

You can see the current list by going to https://launchpad.net/elementary/+milestone/loki-beta1

Currently, there's 39 blueprints linked to the Loki Beta 1 version. The list is constantly being changed and that's perfectly fine for the current state of the release.

The AppCenter is currently being developed and will *probably* be a part of the Loki release, although there's no way of accurately predicting that right now.